# Breaking an LED off a PCB - can it be done?

Tags: led, pcb

I bought a portable humidifier from CVS, and it has a SUPER bright LED inside. I've taken it apart and wrapped it in electric tape, and the tape has muted the light, but not 100%. Maybe 80%.

It's possible to remove (read: break) the LED off the PCB, will this cause any other damage? (irregular voltage or something?)

Comment: Scratch the front of the led with some steel wire kitchen sponge thing, or use a sharpie along with the tape. You could break it off, but without a schematic, we can't tell. And its not a question that will remain open (outside of the scope). Best of luck.

Comment: I'd measure the forwarding voltage across the LED when in use, and replace it with no-so-bright LED having about the same voltage.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words... and it may compensate for not having a schematic, if the circuit is simple and the traces are in view.

Comment: I'd put a small spot of paint over the LED using a cotton-bud. Any opaque paint of any colour should do. I'd let it dry, test and add layers till happy.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll paint + tape it. I didn't know where else to ask, so I went off-topic a bit. Thanks again

Comment: Just for the sake of multiple solutions... I'd desolder the LED and add a resistor in series to dim it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a good idea to try and break an LED off a PCB:

1. Very high likelihood of damaging the PCB in the process, thus making the device inoperable. Desoldering the LED will take a bit more skill, but lower this risk a bit
2. Without seeing the schematic for the PCB, it is impossible to tell what other aspects of the device will be adversely affected by the LED being taken out: The designer may have built in dependencies, such that, for instance, calibration of some aspect of the circuit suffers. Less likely than above, but still true